# How to center my asp.NET panels?

Tags: asp.net, html, visual-studio

I've got panels containing tables to organize textboxes/labels, and I'd like to center them, but I can't figure out what attribute to use. I've tried to justify them in the design view, and horizontalalign:center in html, but to no avail. What's the best way to center panels containing tables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would apply CSS to them:

```
div.myPanelCss
{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

I believe Panels render as a `div`

Answer (score 1):

You can generally center a table by using `margin: auto;`.

Answer (score 0):

Apply the following CSS rule for your panel (surrounding div would work):

```
.centerPanel
{
  margin 0 auto;
}
```